# "NSRangeException" Error, Not Sure Why

Tags: objective-c

I'm making an Objective C program to generate two random arrays and check them for similar numbers. I get the "NSRangeException" on the marked line of code, but  I'm not sure why. Here's my code:

```
// Array Comparator (Check Two Arrays for Similar Numbers)

@interface ArrayComparator: NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray *arrayOne;
    NSMutableArray *arrayTwo;
}

- (void) generateFirstArray;
- (void) generateSecondArray;
- (void) check;

@end

@implementation ArrayComparator

- (void) generateFirstArray
{
    arrayOne = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 50];

    for (NSUInteger n = 0; n < 50; n++)
    {
        [arrayOne addObject: @(arc4random_uniform(999) + 1)];
    }

    for (NSUInteger n = 0; n < 50; n++)
    {
        printf("%li, ", (long) [arrayOne[n] integerValue]);
    }
    printf("first array.\n\n");
}

- (void) generateSecondArray
{
    arrayTwo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 50];

    for (NSUInteger n = 0; n < 50; n++)
    {
        [arrayTwo addObject: @(arc4random_uniform(999) + 1)];
    }

    for (NSUInteger n = 0; n < 50; n++)
    {
        printf("%li, ", (long) [arrayTwo[n] integerValue]);
    }
    printf("second array.\n\n");
}

- (void) check
{
    long similar = 0;

    for (NSUInteger n = 0; n < 50; n++)
    {
        for (NSUInteger m = 0; m < 50; n++)
        {
            if ([arrayOne[n] integerValue] == [arrayTwo[m] integerValue]) // This is where I get the error.
            {
                similar++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("There are %li similar numbers between the two arrays!", similar);
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        ArrayComparator *arrayComp = [[ArrayComparator alloc] init];
        [arrayComp generateFirstArray];
        [arrayComp generateSecondArray];
        [arrayComp check];
    } return 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks. (Please excuse my noobishness.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(NSUInteger m = 0; m < 50; n++)
```

You mean `m++`.